# Centos RAID1 installation

Tags: linux, centos, raid

I have installed Centos 6.2 with RAID1 support, after installation I have checked RAID1 by removing one by one Hard disk, Os booted and worked.

So after I created new users, installed LAMP, ftp and uploaded files.

Then I removed 1st harddisk and booted but what are all created after installation like LAMP, ftp and all are not showing.

But If I go with 2nd Harddisk all the files, users and settings are showing.

In the 1st harddisk showing only Os fresh installation.

Anyone help me to resolve to mirror both harddisk.

Comment: Hardware or software RAID? If hardware: Make and model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Software RAID1 the installer installs to 1 drive and then syncs to the other drive after you have booted the system (this can take quite a while).

You can view the status with:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

I suspect you have powered off the machine before the second drive in the array has been rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

You pulled drive 1 from the array; it is not longer part of the array.

If you want to add it back, you need to tell mdadm to re-add it to the array. I'll assume your 2 drives are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb (Drive 1 and 2 respectively) and your array is /dev/md0

With drive 1 REMOVED, tell mdadm to remove it from the array completely:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1
```

Then add Drive 1 back into the system, and tell mdadm to use that drive as the second part of the array (again):

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1
```

A simple `cat /proc/mdstat` should now show you that the array is resyncing. **Wait for this to finish before you do any more 'testing'**

EDIT: I assumed you were using software RAID, I should have checked first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes I am using software raid and yes our 2 drives are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb.
Could you tell me the exact command for to re-add it to the array.

Comment: The command to re-add the drive is in my answer...